# How to display a listitem in a dropdown list using ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

This is my list definition

```
public class EventsList
    {
        public int EventID { get; set; }
        public string EventName { get; set; }
    }
```

This is C# code

```
string strCurrentUser = CommonWeb.GetLoginUser();
       EventsClass EventObj = new EventsClass();
       DataSet ds;
       List< EventsList> eventList = new List<EventsList>();
       EventsList eventobj = new EventsList();
       ds=EventObj.GetEvents(strCurrentUser);
```

I have a dropdown in which it should have the dropdown menu as the EventName alone. How can I retrieve only the EventName from the list and display that in the dropdown?

Comment: @JleruOhep that is a asp.net dropdown

Comment: In your EventList-Class you can override the ToString-Method and just return the Eventname. Now if you add an object of EventList to your drop-down, in the drop-down will be the EventName

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To display the `EventName` only to the dropdown, you will need to set the following two properties:

- [`DataValueField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datavaluefield.aspx) to `EventId`.
- [`DataTextField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datatextfield.aspx) to `EventName`.

Something like:

```
dropdown.DataSource = ds;
dropdown.DataValueField  = "EventID";
dropdown.DataTextField = "EventName";
dropdown.DataBind();
```

Comment: do we have the properties ValueMember and Displaymember for dropdownlist..?

Comment: @sravan, Sorry they are `DataValueField` and `DataTextField` in asp.net. I thought it is winforms. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
ddlName.DataSource = ds;
ddlName.DataTextField= "EventName";
ddlName.DataValueField= "EventID";
ddlName.DataBind();
```

Here DataValueField is upto you whether to use ID or the Name itself.

Answer (score 0):

In asp.net, you can achieve this like

```
DropDownList1.DataSource = ds;
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "EventName";
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "EventID";
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like also if you have tables in datasource

```
DropDownlist2.DataSource = dataSet.Tables["Table2"];
Dropdownlist2.DataTextField= "SomeTextFieldInTable2";
Dropdownlist2.DataValueField="SomeValueFieldInTable2";
DropDownlist2.DataBind();
```